# Switch back to the main thread in ReactiveCocoa

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, reactive-cocoa

I'm new to ReactiveCocoa, and therefore could miss something obvious. 
I have 2 operations scheduled on the background thread, and after they complete I want to update the UI and for this I need to switch back to the main thread, but I have no idea how.
Here is snippet of code.

```
-(RACSignal *)executeSigninSignal {
    return [[[self.services getAuthenticationService]
             authenticationSignalFor:self.username andPassword:self.password]
            //Return user if exists
            flattenMap:^RACStream *(STUser *user) {
                return [[[[self services] getContactsLoadService]
                 contactsLoadSignalForUser:user]
                //Return user contacts
               doNext:^(NSArray *contacts) {
                   STContactsListViewModel *contactsViewModel =
                   [[STContactsListViewModel alloc] initWithContactsLoadResults:contacts services:self.services];
                   [self.services pushViewModel:contactsViewModel];
               }];
            }];
}
```

`authenticationSignalFor:` and `contactsLoadSignalForUser:` are RACSignals that are delivered on the background thread and I want to execute contents of doNext block on the main thread.

How can I declare that this block should be executed on the main thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `deliverOnMainThread` method before the `doNext:` method.

Comment: Indeed, I tried to use `deliverOnMainThread`, but not in the right place